# Why I cannot render component after using useNavigate hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am new in `React` and `React router`. My problem is, after click on Login button, Home `component` does not render. It justs replace `url` adress from "/" to "/home".

Packages are all installed right. I have checked this out in Network in DevTools, and it really does not render Home component

Why it is happening?

**AppRoutes.js**

```
const AppRoutes = [
  {
        index: true,
        path: "/",
        element: <Layout />
    },
    {
        path: "/home",
        element: <Home/>
    }
];

export default AppRoutes;
```

**Layout.jsx**

```
const Layout = () => {

    const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const getUserIdFromLocalStorage = async () => {
    const id = await localStorage.getItem('userId');

        if (!id) {
            navigate('/');
        } else {
            setUserId(id);
        }
    };

      useEffect(() => {
         
          getUserIdFromLocalStorage();

      }, []);

      return (
          <>
              {userId ? (
                  <>
                      <Sidebar />
                  </>
              ) : (
                  <LoginPage />
              )}
          </>
      );
    }
export default Layout;
```

**LoginPage**

```
const LoginPage =  () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const redirectToHome = () => {
        navigate('/home',
            {
                replace: true
            });
    }
        return (
            <div className="bg-dark text-white">
                <button onClick={redirectToHome}>Login</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
export default LoginPage;
```

**App**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render() {
      return (
          <Routes>
              <Route element={<Layout />}>
                  {AppRoutes.map((route, index) => {
                      const { path, element } = route;
                      return <Route key={index} path={path} element={element} />;
                  })}
              </Route>
          </Routes>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "React routes"? Do you mean React Router? Also, you're showing code that defines `AppRoutes` but you're not showing where you're _using_ that route list, so: are you? Does it get imported by anything anywhere? Because if it doesn't get used, that'd be a pretty good reason for things to not work.

Comment: Yes, I meant React Router. Sorry for misspeling, I have fixed that. And also added file where I am using router @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: Thanks. Could you also fix the indentation and spurious newlines? (you want folks to be able to easily read your code). Running it through an autoformatter like `prettier` should be pretty fast.

Comment: Your code is still badly indented with lots of unnecessary empty lines, so if you really understood, please [edit] your post to fix that =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are rendering `Layout` on a layout route, e.g. a route that renders nested routes, and `Layout` is not rendering an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component for the nested routes to render their `element` content into.

## Suggested Solutions

You have a few options:

1. Refactor `Layout` to render an `Outlet` so the nested routes can also be outputted. Remove the layout route from `AppRoutes`.
2. Keep `Layout` as a regular route component and ***remove*** the "parent" layout route.

Between the two I believe you really want to keep `Layout` as a layout route. Refactor it to render the `Sidebar` and an `Outlet` ***or*** a redirect to a `"/login"` route that renders `Login`.

```
const Layout = () => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(() => {
    // lazy load initial state from localStorage
    return localStorage.getItem('userId');
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  if (userId === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator, spinner, etc...
  }

  return userId
    ? (
      <>
        <Sidebar />
        <div id="main-content">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </>
    ) : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}

export default Layout;
```

```
const AppRoutes = [
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/login",
        element: <LoginPage />
      }
    ],
  },
];

export default AppRoutes;
```

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import AppRoutes from "./AppRoutes";

const router = createBrowserRouter(AppRoutes);

export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render() {
    return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
  }
}
```

or convert `App` to a React function component and use the `useRoutes` hook. No need to reinvent the wheel of mapping/rendering routes.

```
const App = () => {
  const routes = useRoutes(AppRoutes);

  return routes;
}

export default App;
```

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const redirectToHome = () => {
    navigate('/', { replace: true });
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-dark text-white">
      <button onClick={redirectToHome}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: Rease why I have used `Layout`  because I wanted after succesffull auth redirect to the page where will be `Sidebar` and `Outlet` as main content next to each other

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor Rendering `Sidebar` and the content `div` side-by-side is a CSS problem where you just apply the appropriate layout/display rules to get the UI layout you need.

Comment: I don't think it will be CSS issue, if I click for example on Home in Sidebar, it will render Home component, but withouth Sidebar

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your comment. Are you asking about an issue with the sidebar and the way the UI layout renders?

Comment: Yeah, what I have understand(if is not correct, please correct me :) ). The Outlet is component, which contains all Routes. So it gives me question, if AppRoutes file is in your answer, correct.

Comment: To make it more clearier, your solutions works only, if AppRoutes looks like in my question. But it does not make me sense to me. Your Parent-children routes approach seems to me correct.

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor I'm having trouble parsing your last two comments. There's some aspect of my answer that you want or need help understanding how it works? Can you clarify for me please?

Comment: The problem I am having is with `Outlet`. It does not render comopnents together with Sidebar. I used word render, but I think the `AppRoutes` is incorrect. If I click for example on Home in Sidebar, it just show content in Home component withouth Sidebar.

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor "It does not render comopents together with Sidebar." - What does this mean? Is the `Sidebar` rendered or not rendered, to the DOM? If it is rendered then the routes definition is correct and working. If it is not rendered then there might be an error in the console that might inform you what might've happened.

Comment: Sidebar is rendered if the `AppRoutes` are specify like in my question, in your way it does not. In console it says: ,, Objects are not valid as a React child "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254732/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-peter-griffindor).

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. You need to have those Routes wrapped inside a router context.
2. Remove Layout route since you already have that in AppRoutes object.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
  static displayName = App.name;

  render() {
    const AppRoutes = [
      {
        path: "/home",
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Layout />
      }
    ];
    
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {AppRoutes.map((route, index) => {
              const { path, element } = route;
              return <Route key={index} path={path} element={element} />;
            })}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```